# Is this good practice for prevent user without login to access this page? and about querystring

Tags: php, mysql

Assume that I have a page for read cartoon in website  and user that does not login  cannot read this page. 
and my cartoon has many title and each title has many episodes.
(I fetch cartoon image from mysql database use `SELECT * FROM manga WHERE title = $_GET['title'] AND episode = $_GET['episode']`  )

**Question 1**: Should I make 1 page with querystring for many cartoon title and episode  or should I have many page for each cartoon title?

**Question 2**: Is this good practice for prevent user without login to access this page?

now I have 1 page for many cartoon ( use querystring)

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com/manga.php?title=onepiece&episode=10&page=1"> Read One piece </a>  <!-- QUERYSTRING -->
```

in manga.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(empty($_SESSION['is_logged_in']))
    {
       header('Location: restrict_access.php');
    }
    else 
    {  ?>
<!-- Show page -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Whenever you should have one page or multiple depends on your own liking and what you expect your viewers to want. The same goes for your second question. However, your implementation would be fine. Assuming you're able to send the header you would not necessarily need the else part as it would trigger a redirect on the user side.

Comment: I want to make beautiful url  like http://www.foo.com/manga.php/onepiece/10/1

Comment: Can I use htaccess to edit querystring?

Comment: This would be a separate issue and possibly its own question. You would have to look into the rewrite capabilities of the webserver you're using. The rewrite rules could probably be placed in an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Question 1 is about user experience plus canonical/SEO. Just it and nothing more. Question 2, well it's the common way, just after `header` put the `exit()` because the header must be send to browser and didn't prevent the script execution at all. Then the `else` condition isn't necessary. Moreover you can create a page to show the "illegal access" to the user.